# Looping over XAML defined labels

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, loops

I have a WPF application with many labels.

```
<Label x:Name="label1" />
<Label x:Name="label2" />
<Label x:Name="label3" />
....
```

I dont want give every label a value one by one like:

```
label1.content= 1;
label2.content= 20;
label3.content= 30;
....
```

I want do it more like this:

```
for(int i = 1; i<40 ;i++)
{
    label"i".content = i*10;
}
```

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Can you create an array of labels, then loop-through?

Comment: I created my labels in xaml like: <Label x:Name="label1" /> <Label x:Name="label2" />

Comment: Is code-behind an option for creating your labels?

Comment: WPF *application*? Or is this just on one window/control?

Comment: If you have to define every label in XAML, why would adding `Text=1`, `Text=10` etc. be bad? Using code behind, to me, would be more obfuscating than just setting it in XAML.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your labels are all named consistently, you can do it like this:

```
var numberOfLabels = 40;

for(int i = 1; i <= numberOfLabels; i++)
{
    var labelName = string.Format("label{0}", i);
    var label = (Label) this.FindName(labelName);
    label.Content = i * 10;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you work with binding it is easy. You just have to keep your label content in an `ObservableCollection<string>` on your ViewModel. And then, you can do whatever you want with them, in your case iteration.

Edit 1:

Also your xaml should be something like:

```
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyLabelValues}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <sdk:Label Content="{Binding Mode=TwoWay}"></sdk:Label>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Agree. That should be the way to go!

Answer (score 2):

Using this code

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
            if (child != null && child is T)
            {
                yield return (T)child;
            }

            foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
            {
                yield return childOfChild;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can enumerate all controls by type.

```
foreach (Label lbl in FindVisualChildren<Label>(window))
{
    // do something with lbl here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add all those `Label` to a `List<Label>` within the form's constructor.

It is a tedious work, but you'll only have to do it once.

```
List<Label> labels = new List<Label>();
labels.Add(label1);
// etc.

// loop
for (int i = 0; i < labels.Count; i++)
    labels[i].Text = i.ToString();

// alternative loop
foreach (Label label in labels)
    label.Text = "test";
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
List<Label> labelL = new List<Label>();

for(int i = 1; i<40 ;i++)
    labelL.Add(new Label{ Name = "label"+i, Content = i*10 });
```

The end result will be this.

```
label1.Text = 10;
label2.Text = 20;
label3.Text = 20;
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it with binding !

xaml view:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding List}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Content="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

in code behind in the constructor:

```
DataContext = new ViewModelClass();
```

in ViewModelClass:

```
class ViewModelClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }

        private ObservableCollection<StringObject> _List = new ObservableCollection<StringObject>();
        public ObservableCollection<StringObject> List
        {
            get { return _List; }
            set
            {
                _List = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("List");
            }
        }

        public ViewModelClass()
        {
            List = new ObservableCollection<StringObject>
                {
                    new StringObject {Value = "your"},
                    new StringObject {Value = "list"},
                    new StringObject {Value = "of"},
                    new StringObject {Value = "string"}
                };
        }
    }

    public class StringObject
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Be careful with a collection with type `string` it doesn't work, you have to use an object => `StringObject`